# how to retrieve multiple images from web service in windows phone 7Thi

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an application in windows phone 7 where i need to retrieve multiple images from the web service in a single image view and the images should changes when the user swipes it. I tried it in the following way:

My xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageBind }" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="79,61,72,503" Height="187" />
```

This is my image view where i want to display the images.

The cs code:

```
 public class Rest
    {

        public string restaurant_image { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage ImageBind { get; set; }
    }

    public const string RestXml = "Rest.xml";

    public Restaura()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        bool isSuccess;
        //try to load data from iso store
        var doc = ReadXml(out isSuccess);

        if (isSuccess) PopulateList(doc);

        //if failed (data doesn't exists in iso store), download data from web service

        else
        {
            RahmService.RahmSoapClient client = new RahmService.RahmSoapClient();
            client.getRestaurantLocationAllCompleted += new EventHandler<RahmService.getRestaurantLocationAllCompletedEventArgs>(client_getRestaurantLocationAllCompleted);
            client.getRestaurantLocationAllAsync();
        }
    }

    void client_getRestaurantLocationAllCompleted(object sender, RahmService.getRestaurantLocationAllCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        PopulateList(doc);
        WriteXml(doc);
    }
```

Here i am not getting any result. Please help me with code

Comment: Is PopulateList has complete defination ??

Comment: @Jaihind Hey please add the necessary code required if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xaml should be this.

```
<ListBox  Name="ListBoxProduct" >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel>
     <Image Source="{Binding ImageBind }" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="187" /> 
    </StackPanel>                    
   </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In code behind

```
private void PopulateList(XDocument doc)
    {
       List<Rest> restList = new List<Rest>();
        foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))
        {
            Rest data = new Rest();
            data.restaurant_image = location.Element("restaurant_image").Value;
            data.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@" http://........" 
                                             + data.restaurant_image, UriKind.Absolute));
            restList.Add(data);

        }
         ListBoxProduct.ItemsSource= restList;
    }
```

Try this.

Comment: I am getting an error: System.Windows.Controls.listbox doesnot contain a defintion for itemsource

Comment: its ItemsSource not itemsource. I also made changes in ans, give a look.

Comment: Hey there is some problem i think. Application is running but there is no response. Images are not coming

Comment: it's your service problem. i suggest you save image in Isolatedstorage once you get rather than get those images again and again from service

Comment: Yaa i am storing it but for that i need to get the images once.

Comment: Nwys thanks a lot for your help. I have another issue which i want to discuss with you.

Comment: My issue is that from this web method where i am displaying the images there are also some other data which i want to display in textblock. Now there will be multiple data and when users swipes one textblock the image that comes should automatically change corresponding to the data that is displayed. Am i able to make the thing clear. Please reply