# Unable to retrieve image through WCF service in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, image, wcf, windows-phone-8, listbox

I followed this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243289/how-to-retrieve-multiple-images-from-web-service-in-windows-phone-7thi).
Im able to retrieve all the things in ListBox through WCF EXCEPT image. Can somebody help me?

This is my class

```
public Tips()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}

public int TipsId { get; set; }

public string TipsTitle { get; set; }

public string TipsDescription { get; set; }

public string TipsImage { get; set; }

public string TipsCategory { get; set; }

public string ImageBind { get; set; }
```

Service.cs

```
     hairtips = new Tips();
 hairtips.TipsId = myReader.GetInt32(0);
 hairtips.TipsTitle = myReader.GetString(1);
 hairtips.TipsDescription = myReader.GetString(2);
 hairtips.TipsImage = myReader.GetString(3);
 hairtips.TipsCategory = myReader.GetString(4);

 tips.Add(hairtips);
```

After webservice. My .xaml

```
 <ListBox Height="650" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,17,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="434" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Name="LblTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TipsTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="LblDesc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TipsDescription}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"/>

                            <Image x:Name="ImageHair" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="{Binding TipsImage}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

My .cs. I have error under imagebind part.

```
 public HairTips()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string Category = "Hair";

            TipsServiceClient svc = new TipsServiceClient();
            svc.getHairTipsCompleted += new EventHandler<getHairTipsCompletedEventArgs>(svc_getHairTipsCompleted);
            svc.getHairTipsAsync(Category);
        }

  void svc_getHairTipsCompleted(object sender, getHairTipsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
List<Tips> listOfTips = new List<Tips>();
                foreach (var c in e.Result)
            {
             Tips tips  = new Tips();
             tips.TipsTitle = c.TipsTitle;
             tips.TipsDescription = c.TipsDescription;
             tips.TipsImage = c.TipsImage;
             tips.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tips.TipsImage, UriKind.Absolute));
  listOfTips.Add(tips);
        }
            listBox1.ItemsSource = listOfTips;
        }
```

Please help me if you know how to do it. thank you very much

Comment: The specific text of any exceptions raised would be helpful.

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' to 'string'" this is the exception i gotten under tips.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tips.TipsImage, UriKind.Absolute));

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` than using `Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`.

And change your `type` of ImageBind from `String` to  `BitmapImage`.

```
public BitmapImage ImageBind { get; set; }
```

Reference: [Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163604/)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Im unable to put BitmapImage ImageBind {get; set;}
It gave me a red color line under BitmapImage

Comment: what was the error? make sure you add the `namespace` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply. I added the namespace already, but it is telling me that the namespace could not be found